# Меняется ширина и высота картинки при загрузке из drawable

Tags: android

Файл с картинкой лежит в каталоге drawable.

Код загрузки:
picture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.background);

В итоге вместо исходного разрешения (320,5) получаю (240,5)

Разрешение на устройстве 320х240 ~143 ppi как заверяет производитель.

Вродебы по всем условиям картинка не должна масштабироваться. 
Вопрос с чего андроид решил мне так помочь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Вродебы по всем условиям картинка не должна масштабироваться. Вопрос с чего
> андроид решил мне так помочь?

Как раз таки должна - при декодировании ресурса, если дополнительные параметры не указаны явно, то применяются дефолтные. Попробуйте так:

```
  Options opts = new Options();
  opts.inScaled = false;
  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.background, opts);
```

либо декодируйте картинку как не ресурсную, к примеру:

```
  BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getClass().getResourcesAsStream("/res/drawable/image.png"));
```

Answer (score 0):

в drawable должны лежать ресурсы используемые для интерфейса приложения, попробуй положить картинку в Assets

Answer (score 0):

Всем ответившим спасибо. Благодаря Вам я нашел точку где копать и получил ответ.

Как оказалось недра руководств андроида содержат следующую маленькую детальку которая гласит,что если ресурсы положены в drawable без уточнения квалификатора плотности, то по умолчанию подразумевается, что они относятся к mdpi, а у меня прибор ldpi вот и действительно система применила коэффициент 0,75